# FosUserBundle integration with FosRestBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

Does anyone have an example or any idea how one would implement the FOSRestBundle together along with the FOSUserBundle. I have a Web app already developed with Symfony 2 and the FOSUserBundle, but I would like to add the FOSRestBundle for an api layer. I want to be able to pass it a username and password and receive some type of token from the FOSUserBundle that represents the logged in user that I can then pass and forth between other api calls. Does anyone know of a good way to do this?

Comment: By the way keep in mind to update the FOSUserBundle to the latest version, there was some security issues. Check out the Symfony Blog for more information: http://symfony.com/blog/security-release-fosuserbundle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FOSUserBundle` should be natively "restful" meaning that it may follow the REST recommandations.

However, it is not designed to work natively with `FOSRestBundle`, the simplest way to do that is to override the UsersController in your Bundle and adapt your actions.

For example, to allow RESTFul registration, you may write the following action:

```
    public function postUsersAction()
    {
        $form = $this->container->get('fos_user.registration.form');
        $formHandler = $this->container->get('fos_user.registration.form.handler');
        $confirmationEnabled = $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.registration.confirmation.enabled');

        $process = $formHandler->process($confirmationEnabled);

        if ($process) {
            $user = $form->getData();
            $authUser = false;

            if ($confirmationEnabled) {
            } else {
                $authUser = true;
            }

            $response = new Response();

            if ($authUser) {
                /* @todo Implement authentication */
                //$this->authenticateUser($user, $response);
            }

            $response->setStatusCode(Codes::HTTP_CREATED);
            $response->headers->set(
                'Location',
                $this->generateUrl(
                    'api_users_get_user',
                    array('user' => $user->getId()),
                    true
                )
            );

            return $response;
        }

        return RestView::create($form, Codes::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```